# Calling function when last instance of class is destructed / overwrited

Tags: c++, reference-counting

I'm trying to create a class wrapping fopen() / fclose() / f* methods. I want to use this method for other purposes, that's why I don't want to use smart pointers.

The problem is I don't know when to call fclose() or other 'end of life' functions. Destructor could be called but in the meantime FILE * was copied to another object for example by copy constructor.

I tried writing 'Reference Counter' class (that will be base class of all classes) but unfortunately I'm not able to call pure virtual methods from constructor / destructor.

This is what I've tried:

```
class ReferenceCounter
{
    public:
        ReferenceCounter()
        {
            ReferenceCount = new unsigned int(0);
            AddRef();
        }
        ReferenceCounter(const ReferenceCounter & CopyFrom)
        {
            ReferenceCount = CopyFrom.ReferenceCount;
            AddRef();
        }
        ReferenceCounter & operator = (const ReferenceCounter & AssignFrom)
        {
            RemoveRef();
            ReferenceCount = AssignFrom.ReferenceCount;
            AddRef();

            return *this;
        }
        ~ReferenceCounter()
        {
            RemoveRef();
        }

        virtual void OnInit() = 0;
        virtual void OnDestruct() = 0;
    private:
        unsigned int * ReferenceCount;

        void AddRef()
        {
            if(++*ReferenceCount == 1)
                OnInit();
        }
        void RemoveRef()
        {
            if(--*ReferenceCount == 0)
            {
                OnDestruct();
                delete ReferenceCount;
            }
        }
};
```

Maybe there is a way to 'overwrite' or 'overlay' one class over another?

Example:

```
class File
{
    public:
        File(std::string FileName)
        {
            F = fopen(FileName.c_str(), ...);
        }
        ~File()
        {
            fclose(F);
        }
    private:
        FILE * F;
};

int main()
{
    File File1("a.txt");
    auto File2 = File1;

    //SegFault = fclose called twice for File1 and File2
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is here.  Could you illustrate?

Comment: You should alter your "file" class so that it isn't copyable or assignable.  Then this problem goes away.  If you need to pass around "copies" of it then consider passing around instances of `std::shared_ptr<your_file_class>`, which will do exactly this kind of reference counting for you.

Comment: Agree with @cdhowie; this is exactly what smart pointers are designed to solve.

Comment: Ok, I provided example.

Answer (score 3):

There are two solutions here, which work in tandem.

First, don't allow assignment or copying of your "file handle" class.<sup>1</sup>

```
class File
{
    // C++11 solution: use =delete
    public:
        File(File & const) = delete;
        File & operator=(File & const) = delete;

    // C++ < 11 solution: make them private and *don't implement them*:
    private:
        File(File & const);
        File & operator=(File & const);
};
```

Second, consider only passing references to a single `File` object.  (The compiler won't let you copy `File` objects anymore, so if you are doing this by accident you will get a compiler error -- this is good, because it will help you identify areas you need to fix.)

If it's too difficult to establish a single point of ownership, then consider instead passing instances using `std::shared_ptr<File>` which does exactly the kind of reference counting you are trying to implement -- the `File` will be deleted (and therefore its destructor called) when the last `std::shared_ptr` is itself destructed.

```
auto file = std::make_shared(new File{"a.txt"});
auto file2 = file;
// file.use_count() and file2.use_count() are now both 2.
//
// When file2 is destructed this will drop to 1; when file is destructed this will
// drop to 0, and the File object will be deleted.
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that you could probably implement copying using [`dup()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html), though semantics for assignment may be a bit trickier -- should assignment close the existing handle and `dup()` the handle being assigned?  If you do implement `dup()` functionality I would be more inclined to make it a member function instead so that its usage is explicit instead of happening automatically when you may not intend it to.

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now. I create 'ForbidCopying' class and deleted copy constructor and assign operator. All classes are derived from it.

Comment: @peku33 Then all that is left to do is use `std::shared_ptr`, or pass instances of `File` by reference (`File &`) depending on your particular needs. (It's safe to accept a `File &` as long as you don't retain a reference/pointer to it beyond the lifetime of the object.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a shared pointer with `fclose` as deleter:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>

class File
{
    private:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<FILE> shared_file;

    public:
    // You might consider const char*
    File(const std::string& FileName, const std::string& Mode)
    :   F(std::fopen(FileName.c_str(),  Mode.c_str()), fclose)
    {
        if( ! F.get()) {
            throw std::runtime_error("File Open Failure");
        }
    }

    private:
    shared_file F;
};

int main()
{
    File File1("/tmp/test.txt", "r");
    auto File2 = File1;
}
```

Comment: If going this route I would suggest using a lambda instead of `fclose` directly, because if you pass in `fclose` then deleting becomes a function pointer call, which is more expensive than using a lambda (which can be inlined). (`F(std::fopen(...), [] (FILE *f) { fclose(f); })`)

Comment: @cdhowie What makes you think the indirection through a lambda using fclose is more efficient? It could add additional functionality, but a freestanding (or static member) function could do so, too.

Comment: A lambda will result in a compiler-generated functor, which will always be more efficient than making a function pointer call. A free-standing or static function is going to have the same pitfall as using `fclose` directly -- it will make a function pointer call, which is very slow. A lambda will generate a functor; the functor won't be making a function pointer call; the functor `operator()` will almost certainly be inlined; it will be more efficient.

Comment: I would also add that semantically, `File` should not be copyable.  I know that in your implementation it is safe, but it is also *confusing* in that now you have an object that represents a file handle but you can have copies that all refer to the same handle inadvertently.  Requiring the class user to wrap it in an `std::shared_ptr` means that *they* are making the decision regarding having multiple object handles to the same file handle, and this decision is readily apparent.  By hiding the `shared_ptr` within the class, users may be blindsided by unintentional copies being the same handle.